# Discord.js Array coming as undefined

Tags: javascript, discord.js

The command is taking in an image and some text with it in channel-1 and posting the same image and text in channel-2.
The image gets posted but the text comes out as undefined but when i print out the value in the console it is not empty.

Input in channel -1
[input in channel 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CuxzM.png)

Output in channel 2
[Output in channel 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zvbe2.png)

Code

```
    if(!args.length){
        return message.channel.send(`${message.author} There was no input,Command: ${message} ,your input: ${args}`);
    }
    var str= args.toString();
    const values=str.split(' ');
    client.channels.cache.get("channel-id").send({
        files:Array.from(message.attachments.values()),
        content:`${values[1]}`
    });
    console.log(values);
    client.channels.cache.get("channel-id").send(`here it is --- ${values[1]}`);
}
```

Console-

```
Ready
[ 'hello,world' ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is with your implementation. You are accessing values[1] whereas in the console.log() it appears the values array has only one element i.e at values[0]